# Replace ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement with an ASPxButton

Tags: aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView in which I use a custom EditForm and I'd like to replace the default UpdateButton constructed by dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement with a dx:ASPxButton instead

So, this

```
<dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="UpdateButton" ReplacementType="EditFormUpdateButton" runat="server" />
```

Should be something like this

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Text="Spara" />
```

Any advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable `AutoPostBack` (set it to false), and use the `client side Click event` on the Button to Validate the Update form & trigger Update as shown below:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Text="Spara" AutoPostBack= "false">
    <ClientSideEvents Click="OnUpdateClick"></ClientSideEvents>
</ASPxButton>

//JavaScript to hadle Update Button Click
function OnUpdateClick(s,e)
{
    if (ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('mygroup'))
        grid.UpdateEdit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way shown on the dev express support site:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S130677.aspx

```
<Templates>
<EditForm>
    <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="tr1" runat="server" ReplacementType="EditFormEditors" />
    <table style="float: right">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="b1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" AutoPostBack="false"
                    Text="Update">
                    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s){grid.UpdateEdit();}" />
                </dx:ASPxButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="b2" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" AutoPostBack="false"
                    Text="Cancel">
                    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s){grid.CancelEdit();}" />
                </dx:ASPxButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EditForm>
```